# How to use Bulk Insert in Entity Framework using Object Context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I would like to use Object Context instead of DbContext to call Bulk Insert in Entity Framework 6. How can I do that?

I would like to do something like

readonly **ObjectContext obContext**:

```
public void BulkInsert<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class, new()
{
    obContext.BulkInsert(items);
}
```

But I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With entity framework 6, you can use this nice nuget package to bulk insert, and you can use it with the DbContext object.

so something like this:

```
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
   EFBatchOperation.For(db, db.BlogPosts).InsertAll(list);
}
```

https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the question was about ObjectContext, was it not?

Comment: Doesn't apply to ObjectContext as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

With EntityFrame 6 you do insert a range of elements.

For example, i add a model **Customer**

```
public class Customer
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string CustomerName {get;set;}
  public string City {get;set;}
}
```

If I send List of customer from view like List of models (List), I can save range of data like:

```
public ActionResult AddCustomerData(List<Customer> cust)
{
  try
  {
    using(var db = new DBContext)
    {
      db.customer.AddRange(cust);
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
  catch(exception ex)
  {
  }
}
```

Like this you can add bulk/range of data to tha database and before adding you can modify data if you want also. Thank you.